# fetching data in redux using Axios Get

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, thunk

The endpoint is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api` and I can see the data if I go to that endpoint in my browser.

amazonslice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";


export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "amazon/getProducts",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api')
    return response.data;
  }
)

const initialState = {
  allProducts: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: false,
};

export const amazonSlice = createSlice({
  name: "amazon",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    })
    builder.addCase(getProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.allProducts = action.payload;
    })
    builder.addCase(getProducts.rejected, (state) => {
      state.error = true;
    });
},
```

export default amazonSlice.reducer;

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import amazonReducer from "./amazonSlice";
import { ThunkMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, amazonReducer)


// The Global Store Setup
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {amazon: persistedReducer},
middleware: [thunk]

});

export let persistor = persistStore(store)
```

productfeed.js

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getProducts } from '@/slices/amazonSlice'
const ProductFeed = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const allProducts = useSelector((state) => state.amazon);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts())
}, [])
console.log(allProducts) 

return (
<div>
    some paragraph
</div>
)
}

export default ProductFeed
```

When I run `productfeed.js` in browser, I can see the api request in the `network` tab but the data are show as `allProducts: Array(0)` in console but in `network` tab, the data are being fetched with `200` status. Any other `redux` usecase in my application working fine. I am just trying to make `api` request in the redux since people told me it is a good practice.